# Using VBA in Excel to Create a History

Tags: excel, vba

To start off, I am working in security and have little coding experience.

I'm creating an excel sheet to help automate my job a little. This sheet keeps track of officers. So far I have 4 columns. One for the officer name, one for whether they're available or unavailable, one for what kind of task they're doing, and one for what time I changed their status (available or unavailable).

I used VBA to get and format the time when I change the status and I also have it delete the task name automatically when I change the status to available.

Here's what I have already:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MyTime, MyTimeNow 

    Dim wk As Workbook

    Set wk ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws ActiveSheet

    Application.EnableEvents = True
  
    MyTime = Now()

    WatchedColumn = 2 

    BlockedRow = 1

    TimestampColumn = 4

    Crow = Target.Row

    CColumn = Target.Column 

    MyTimeNow = Format (MyTime, "hh:nn:ss")

    If CColumn = WatchedColumn And Crow> BlockedRow Then

    Cells (Crow, TimestampColumn) = MyTimeNow

    End If

    Dim rngCheck As Range

    Dim rngToDelete As Range 

    Dim intersectRange As Range

    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngCheck Me.Range("B:B")

    Set rngToDelete Me.Range("C:C")

    Set intersectRange Intersect (Target, rngCheck)

    It Not intersect Range Is Nothing Then 

    For Each cell in IntersectRange

    If cell.Value = "Available" Then

    Me.Cells(cell.Row, rnoToDelete.Column).ClearContents

    End If 

    Next cell

    End If

    End Sub
```

What I need now is to create a log starting in cell A21 and going down, that whenever I change an officers status to unavailable records "[Officer name] became [Status] at [Time] for [Task]" or when changing back creates a log "[Officer Name] became [Status] at [Time]".

I have been using ChatGPT to help me write the code but everything it creates gives me errors or breaks my old code. Here's what it gave me:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCheck As Range

    Dim rngToDelete As Range

    Dim intersectRange As Range

    Dim cellToCheck As Range ' Rename 'cell' variable to 'cellToCheck'

    Dim logRow As Long

    

    ' Set the range to monitor for changes (B column)

    Set rngCheck = Me.Range("B:B")

    

    ' Set the range to delete (C column)

    Set rngToDelete = Me.Range("C:C")

    

    ' Check if any changed cell intersects with the range to monitor

    Set intersectRange = Intersect(Target, rngCheck)

    

    If Not intersectRange Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        

        ' Find the next empty cell in column A starting from A21

        logRow = Me.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If logRow < 21 Then logRow = 21

        

        ' Process each changed cell

        For Each cellToCheck In intersectRange ' Update variable name to 'cellToCheck'

            ' Check if the value of the corresponding cell in column B is "Available"

            If cellToCheck.Value <> "Available" Then

                ' Create the formatted string

                Dim nameValue As String

                Dim currentValue As String

                Dim incidentValue As String

                Dim logEntry As String

                

                nameValue = Me.Cells(cellToCheck.Row, "A").Value

                currentValue = cellToCheck.Value

                incidentValue = Me.Cells(cellToCheck.Row, "D").Value

                

                logEntry = nameValue & " became " & currentValue & " at " & incidentValue & " for " & Me.Cells(cellToCheck.Row, "C").Value

                

                ' Write the log entry in the next empty cell in column A

                Me.Range("A" & logRow).Value = logEntry

                

                ' Increment to the next empty row

                logRow = logRow + 1

            End If

        Next cellToCheck ' Update variable name in 'Next' statement

        

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

    

    ' Add your existing code here

    ' ...

    ' ...

    ' ...

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is your question? What is working? What is not working? What error do you get? (have you checked/searched the error messages?)

Comment: I guess I'm just looking for direction on how to create the log. The errors I've been getting are things like "Me keyword used improperly" and runtime error 1104 or something similar to those. Again, I'm sorry, I don't have any formal training and only very limited experience with coding. I was hoping ChatGPT would work but it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to SO.

There were quite a few bugs in your code, not limited to:

- Duplicate variable declarations (dim statements)
- When you use Set, you must say Set varName = Value. You were missing the equals sign
- Wrong use of EnableEvents

Generally I recommend always putting this at the top of every code module:

```
Option Explicit
```

This ensures that missing variable declarations cause an error. It makes it more difficult to accidentally declare variables implicitly (i.e. start using it before you've Dim'd it).

Second recommendation I have is that when you have the code in the condition where you **think** it's OK, go to Debug>Compile VBA Project. This will check all your code for errors. You should keep trying to compile it until you get no more errors.

Anyway, I changed the code and now it does this:

[image]

It's likely not perfect, but we can discuss other changes if you need help with it.

Here's the modified version of your code, with logging code included.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print Target.Address & " was changed"

    ' for values that aren't reassigned, use Const
    Const nameCol As Integer = 1
    Const watchedCol As Integer = 2
    Const taskCol As Integer = 3
    Const timestampCol As Integer = 4
    Const watchAfterRow As Integer = 1
    Const logStartRow As Integer = 21

    ' put all variable declarations at the top
    Dim changedAt As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim intersectRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim logRow As Integer
    Dim logMessage As String
    Dim task As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    changedAt = Format(Now(), "hh:nn:ss")
    
    Set intersectRange = Intersect(Target, ws.Columns(watchedCol))

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    If Not intersectRange Is Nothing Then
    
        Debug.Print "...changes to column " & watchedCol

        For Each cell In intersectRange
        
            If cell.Row > watchAfterRow And cell.Row < logStartRow Then
            
                Debug.Print "...changes to rows greater than " & watchAfterRow
        
                ws.Cells(cell.Row, timestampCol) = changedAt
                
                Debug.Print "..." & ws.Cells(cell.Row, timestampCol).Address & " changed to " & changedAt
                Debug.Print "..." & cell.Address & " changed to " & cell.Value
                
                If cell.Value = "Available" Then
                    ws.Cells(cell.Row, taskCol).ClearContents
                    Debug.Print "...column " & taskCol & " cleared"
                End If
                
                task = ws.Cells(cell.Row, taskCol)
                
                If task = "" Then task = "<No task specified>" Else task = task
                
                logMessage = ws.Cells(cell.Row, nameCol) & _
                                " became " & cell.Value & _
                                " at " & changedAt _
                                & IIf(cell.Value <> "Available", " for task " & task, "")
                                
                If ws.Cells(logStartRow, 1) = "" Then
                    logRow = logStartRow
                Else
                    logRow = ws.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End If
                     
                ws.Cells(logRow, 1) = logMessage
                
            End If
    
        Next cell

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your post was informative, but you missed the actual question. OP wanted to know how to log the row based on the status column.

Comment: You're right. I've edited it to add the logging code.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the welcome, detailed answer, and explanations! It's so above and beyond what I asked for or knew to ask for I'm blown away. From this post alone I'm blown away with how great the community is here on SO. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const COL_NAME = 1 ' A
    Const COL_STATUS = 2 ' B
    Const COL_TASK = 3 ' C
    Const COL_TIME = 4 ' D
   
    Dim status As String, logmsg As String, timestamp As String
    Dim logrow As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    
    ' target cell
    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column
    
    ' change not in range
    If (r < 2) Or (c <> COL_STATUS) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' log change
    On Error GoTo myerror
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    timestamp = Format(Now(), "hh:nn:ss")
    Cells(r, COL_TIME) = timestamp
    
    status = LCase(Target.Value)
    logmsg = Cells(r, COL_NAME) & " became " & status & " at " & timestamp
    logrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If logrow < 21 Then logrow = 21
    
    If status = "available" Then
        Cells(logrow, 1) = logmsg
        Cells(r, COL_TASK).ClearContents

    ElseIf status = "unavailable" Then
        Cells(logrow, 1) = logmsg & " for " & Cells(r, COL_TASK)
    Else
        MsgBox "Status = " & status & " ?", vbExclamation
    End If
    
myerror:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite the event code and add log function.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyTimeNow, sStatus As String, sLog As String
    Dim rngDes As Range
    Dim WatchedColumn, BlockedRow, TimestampColumn, ToDeleteColumn
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    WatchedColumn = 2
    BlockedRow = 1
    TimestampColumn = 4
    ToDeleteColumn = 3
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            sStatus = .Value
            If .Column = WatchedColumn And .Row > BlockedRow Then
                MyTimeNow = Format(Now, "hh:nn:ss")
                Cells(.Row, TimestampColumn) = MyTimeNow
                sLog = Cells(.Row, 1) & " became " & sStatus & " at " & MyTimeNow
                If UCase(sStatus) = "AVAILABLE" Then
                    Cells(.Row, ToDeleteColumn).ClearContents
                ElseIf UCase(sStatus) = "UNAVAILABLE" Then
                    sLog = sLog & " for " & Cells(.Row, ToDeleteColumn)
                Else
                    sLog = ""
                End If
                If Len(sLog) Then
                    rngDes = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    If rngDes.Row < 21 Then Set rngDes = Cells(21, 1)
                    rngDes.Value = sLog
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand anything you just did, but that's incredible, thank you so much!

Comment: It's just a typical Change event code. Hope it is helpful for you.